# regular expression accepting email from specific domain

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

looking for regular expression for email which will accept
email id from specific domain like 
i want it to accept email only from org so valid emails will be

```
avc@gddf.org
lmn@sdf.org
sdfsdf@sdfsdf.org
```

It should not accept email other than .org 
may i knw how it is possible

Answer (score 1):

You don't need regex here. Just use [EndsWith()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2333wewz%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
string email= "azf@example.org";
Console.WriteLine(email.EndsWith(".org"));
```

> True

```
string email= "azf@example.orgg";
Console.WriteLine(email.EndsWith(".org"));
```

> False

Comment: i want regular expression to do it on client side

Comment: @Fattycoder next time write it **in** the question. Did you, at least, search a bit?